# IP address from Iran blocked in Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, ip-address, firewall, country

One of my users from Iran is unable to connect to port 80/443 which is open otherwise on the GCP

```
mtr -rw 35.229.29.0
HOST: ir-hs01.xxxx.com Loss% Snt Last Avg Best Wrst StDev
1. 185-173-105-113.static.hostiran.name 0.0% 10 1.2 0.6 0.3 2.4 0.7
2. 10.201.42.169 0.0% 10 1.1 0.5 0.4 1.1 0.2
3. 10.201.43.1 0.0% 10 2.4 5.1 2.2 26.4 7.5
4. 10.201.22.113 0.0% 10 3.6 2.5 2.2 3.6 0.4
5. 10.202.4.9 0.0% 10 1.6 1.7 1.5 2.0 0.1
6. 10.202.4.77 0.0% 10 1.8 1.9 1.8 2.0 0.1
7. 10.21.21.10 0.0% 10 2.4 2.2 2.0 2.5 0.1
8. 10.21.21.10 0.0% 10 1.9 2.0 1.9 2.3 0.2
9. de-cix.fra.google.com 0.0% 10 73.7 74.8 72.9 90.0 5.4
10. 108.170.251.209 0.0% 10 73.7 73.7 73.6 73.8 0.1
11. 209.85.240.113 0.0% 10 73.5 73.6 73.4 74.0 0.2
12. 216.239.50.187 0.0% 10 83.8 83.8 83.7 84.1 0.1
13. 216.239.54.148 0.0% 10 158.4 158.5 158.2 159.1 0.2
14. 209.85.255.146 0.0% 10 171.2 171.3 171.0 171.6 0.2
15. 72.14.238.123 0.0% 10 170.9 171.2 170.9 172.5 0.5
16. ??? 100.0 10 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

The MTR report shows the traffic is entering Google premium network at France and it gets blocked at a later stage

Why is the IP blocked?

Comment: I cant ping the iranian IP from the GCE compute instance too . mtr shows it is being blocked in my computes network itself

Answer (score 0):

Google restricts access to some of its business services in certain countries according to the following [list](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2891389?hl=en) including Iran.

There is not an official list for Compute Engine. I would recommend using the provided [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2891389?hl=en) until one specifically for GCE is created.

Comment: That's a really sad thing to do and it affects my business too as I have customers from countries like Iran